# Запись в переменную куска видео

Tags: python, ffmpeg

Пытаюсь сохранить результат в переменную `result`, результатом является обработанный видео кусок...

**Как правильно сохранить обработанный кусок видео в переменную result?**

Кусок кода:

```
def Response(request):
    chunkVideo = next(threads[0].run())

    chunkVideo = ffmpeg.input(chunkVideo, f='mp4')

    result = b""
    chunkVideo = ffmpeg.filter(chunkVideo, 'fps', fps=10, round='up')
    chunkVideo = ffmpeg.output(chunkVideo, result, f="mp4")
    ffmpeg.run(chunkVideo)

    return HttpResponse(result)
```

Ошибка:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc6 in position 31: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Ну, вы всё сохранили. А зачем вы пытаетесь напечатать байты с видео на экран через print(result)? Питон не понимает, как это сделать, как сконвертировать эти байты в кодировку UTF-8.

Comment: @CrazyElf, но он не хочет сохранять, пишет ошибку. Ошибка появляется на моменте ffmpeg.run()... Ошибка появляется не из-за print(result)

Comment: @XOOTO Судя по примерам и сигнатуре там ожидается название файла где вы поместили result: `ffmpeg.output(stream1[, stream2, stream3…], filename, **ffmpeg_args)`

Comment: @CrazyElf, а есть ли возможность сохранить в переменную?

Comment: @XOOTO Можно вроде pipe делать и читать из него. Смотрите примеры в документации: https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CrazyElf, в комментарии написал "Можно вроде pipe делать и читать из него. Смотрите примеры в документации: kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python - CrazyElf", благодаря ему этот вопрос решён.

Comment: Отлично, что всё получилось. Бывает, что я ответ не знаю, но у меня есть версия, которую стоит проверить.

Comment: Это просто заблуждение. `pipe:` выдает на стандартный вывод точно то же самое, что бы выводил в файл, т. е. путаницу символов. Единственным разумным применением `pipe:` является вывод в **rawvideo**-формате (для последующего ввода в другую программу для обработки). Но **rawvideo** выбросит всякую метаинформацию, сохраняя только биты отдельных снимков. *Значит, ваша обработка (изменение FPS)* всё равно **сохранена не будет**.

Comment: *«...благодаря ему этот вопрос решён.»* - Как решён?  В вашем ответе это не объяснено, не вижу команду типа  `result = ...` (ваш вопрос был **«Как правильно сохранить обработанный кусок видео в переменную result?»**). Добавите это, пожалуйста.

Comment: @MarianD, pipe возвращает (в переменную) в ЛЮБОМ ФОРМАТЕ, pipe не только работает с rawvideo.
И с этой переменной я уже могу работать. Мне это и нужно была. Перейдите по ссылке, что указал CrazyElf и во всём разберётесь.

Comment: *«...pipe возвращает (в переменную)...»* - нет, в никакую переменную, только в стандартный вывод. Потому вы не способен просто написать соответствующую команду присвоения. *«...в ЛЮБОМ ФОРМАТЕ...»* - да, но зачем? В конце концов для последующей обработки вы были бы вынуждены своим собственным кодом конвертировать его в rawvideo! Я приведу аналогию: Когда вы хотите работать с файлом в ZIP архиве, вы вынуждены в первую очередь вытянуть его с ZIP-архива. Смотрите, я знаю, о чем говорю, я хотел вам помочь. Когда вам более приятно остаться в заблуждении, я не могу ничего для вас сделать.

Comment: @MarianD, так, по поводу pipe, что только с rawvideo работает. Да, вы правы, я попробовал напрямую поработать с ffmpeg через subprocess.Popen, и там pipe:1 работает только с rawvideo... Но если использовать модуль ffmpeg-python + ffmpeg, то с pipe уже приятнее работать. Но думаю если посидеть напрямую с ffmpeg через subprocess.Popen, то можно будет сделать "-f 'webm' pipe:1"... Ещё раз повторюсь, что вы правы. Но всё равно правильный ответ за CrazyElf. Но и вам на этом спасибо большое.

Comment: Напишите команду `result = ...`. Это была, конечно, суть вашего вопроса. Всё остальное только пустые разговоры.

Answer (score 1):

Надо понять, что вам **нечего сохранять** - у вас нету никакого (промежуточного) результата, потому что его просто не может быть.

Всё, что *ffmpeg-python* делает, есть постепенное составление цепочки параметров для программы *FFmpeg*, точнее, для его консольной команды `ffmpeg`.

Только после передачи созданной цепочки как параметра в функцию `ffmpeg.run()` (или `ffmpeg.run_async()`) пакета *ffmpeg-python* делается работа, но эту работу уже делает *сама программа FFmpeg,* а не пакет *ffmpeg-python*.

---

С другой стороны, всё что вы сделали, будет сохранено в вашей переменной `chunkVideo` после (например) *правильной* команды

```
chunkVideo = ffmpeg.output(chunkVideo, "output.mp4")
```

(а не вашей неправильной `chunkVideo = ffmpeg.output(chunkVideo, result, f="mp4")`), но только в виде объекта типа `OutputStream`, что опять *нечего другого как цепочка параметров для `ffmpeg`.*

Вы можете убедиться в том: `ffmpeg.get_args(chunkVideo)` вам покажет список этих параметров (аргументов).